# If there is a 1% chance with 100 repetitions, and a 5% chance with 20 repetitions, why aren't the probabilities of an occurence the same?

Tags: probability, statistics

So if we have a 1% chance and 100 instances there's a ~63% chance of an occurence. If we have a 5% chance and 20 instances, the probability of an occurence is ~64%. And if we have a 33.3% chance with 3 instances the probablity is ~70%. What is causing this difference? It seems counterintuitive, though I understand that it has to grow too because 100% chance with one instance is a 100% chance of occurence after all. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are $n$ independent attempts each with probability $p$ of success then the probability of at least one success is $1$ minus the probability of no successes, so $$1-(1-p)^n$$

If $p=\frac1n$ then this is $$1-\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n$$ which tends towards $1-e^{-1}\approx 0.63212$ as $n$ increases.  We can even give a series: $$1-\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n\approx 1- \frac1e + \frac1{2e n} + \frac5{24e n^2}+ \frac5{48e n^3}+\cdots$$ so you can see it is slightly higher for small $n$

Comment: Thank you really much for your answer!! I understand the reasoning, but I still don't quite understand why. Why does it tend toward 1−e^−1? Is there any significance to this?

Comment: @Nils - it is reasonable to expect to converge to something (the mean number of successes is $1$, but some are greater than $1$ and some are $0$). One way of thinking about this is where a binomial distribution converges in distribution to a Poisson distribution.  $1-e^{-1}$ appears in the answers to many questions on this site ranging from recruiting secretaries to seating married couples; here are a few that explicitly say [0.63212](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=0.63212)

Answer (score 0):

The sense you're getting that they all ought to be the same is reasonable, because all of those distributions have the exact same Expected Value for their number of successes, that being 1.  The difference is that the more repetitions, the higher the chance of getting more than one success, which counts multiple times for the expected value, but only once for the binary "was there at least one success" question.